# Kibana (current version) - Not showing string type fields in visualization

Tags: charts, line, visualization, kibana

I am using current version of Kibana, not showing string type fields to select for x-axis (Line or Bar charts). Am I missing anything here?
Here is my sample json. How to breakdown by `IterationName`?

**JSON**

```
{
  "iterationName":"Sprint 60",
  "manualEffortInSec":300,
  "automationEffortInSec":100,
  "hrlyRate":150,
  "manualEffortCost":750,
  "automationEffortCost":250,
  "verdictInteger":1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for visualizing fields in buckets(x-axis) you should, for example, choose the "Terms" and under that choose your field which is "iterationName".
this part shows all the fields regardless of their type.
maybe there is a problem in your mapping, it is better to go to the discover tab and check the fields of your index pattern to see if all the fields are indexed or not